# PHP :: radio button value is always set as "on" after form submission

Tags: php

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value"female"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn">
</form>
```

$_POST['sex'] = always I see the below output for the radio button:

See = string 'on'

It always gives "on" instead of male or female. This is what I have put in the form.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Please help.

If I use SELECT box, then it works well. But I need to make it work using radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Male : <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked /><br/>
Female : <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="btn">
</form>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo $_REQUEST['sex'];
?>
```

Above code is working, Changes

```
value = female
```

you forgot to add *=* sign

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>
```

you didn't put equal to sign near female.

Comment: Thank you all for the correcting. My mistake , I missed that equal sign :(               Thank you again for spotting it. Really helps. I was a sad yesterday, but I am extremely happy now. Because I have an interview next week :)

Comment: @jcoder mark the question as answered , best of luck for your interview ,this is a best platform to sort out your doubts .

Comment: Thank you ben for your answer. Unfortunately I was not selected, but I will keep trying other jobs :)

Comment: @jcoder  we learn from failure, so don't repeat the mistake again .